# Apache Camel: MethodNotFoundException, Failed to invoke method on null due to: MethodNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I try following a video tutorial for Apache Camel education and trying aggregate queue objects in a next way:

```java
@Component
public class AggregationRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:files/json")
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, CurrencyExchange.class)
                    .aggregate(simple("${body.to}"), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy()) // <--- (1)
                    .completionSize(3)// <----- (2)
                .to("log:aggregation");
    }
}
```

CurrencyExchange model:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CurrencyExchange {
    public int id;
    public String from;
    public String to;
    public BigDecimal conversionMultiple;
}
```

Aggregation implementation:

```java
public class ArrayListAggregationStrategy implements AggregationStrategy {
    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        Object newObject = newExchange.getIn().getBody();
        ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if(oldExchange == null){
            list.add(newObject);
            newExchange.getIn().setBody(list);
            return newExchange;
        } else {
            oldExchange.getIn().getBody(list.getClass()).add(newObject);
            return oldExchange;
        }
    }
}
```

First of all - the code works correctly without (1) and (2) lines.
When I uncommented these lines, I get the error:

```
> 2022-05-12 12:34:26.913 ERROR 82201 --- [le://files/json]
> o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for
> (MessageId: F948EB377E1DB38-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId:
> F948EB377E1DB38-0000000000000000). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1
> caught: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException:
> Failed to invoke method: to on null due to:
> org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with
> name: to not found on bean:
> com.education.camelmicroservicea.model.CurrencyExchange@301f4095 of
> type: com.education.camelmicroservicea.model.CurrencyExchange on the
> exchange: Exchange[F948EB377E1DB38-0000000000000000]
```

Stacktrace:

```
> org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed
> to invoke method: to on null due to:
> org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with
> name: to not found on bean:
> com.education.camelmicroservicea.model.CurrencyExchange@301f4095 of
> type: com.education.camelmicroservicea.model.CurrencyExchange on the
> exchange: Exchange[F948EB377E1DB38-0000000000000000]  at
> org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.invokeOgnlMethod(BeanExpression.java:453)
> ~[camel-bean-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]   at
> org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:199)
> ~[camel-bean-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0] .....
```

- Please note, that the error message: `Failed to invoke method: to on null due to:` means method `to`, so it can sound like **Failed to invoke method: `to()` on null due to:**

---

Why the `simple` through this exception, if I receive the body in the correct way?

Comment: It seems the lombok does not work properly for reflection. Closed

Comment: As a workaround, try to define a public wrapper method around : `public String wrapTo() { return this.to(); } ` and use this method in Camel expr (ie `simple("${body.wrapTo}")`

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need to trust Lombok when u use reflection.

After I added getter handly, all works fine:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CurrencyExchange {
    private int id;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;

    public String getTo(){
        return this.to;
    }
}
```